# echo product description if the products belongs to specific category

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category

On my category pages I want to display the product description under the product if it belongs to a specific category. This is what I've tried:

```
<?php
    $catdesc=true;
    $categoryId = $_product->getCategoryId();
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($categoryId);
    if($category->getCatdesc()==428){
        $catdesc=true;
        break;
}
?>

<?php if($catdesc): ?>
    <span><?php echo $_product->getDescription(); ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It get's the product description alright, however for any product- whether it belongs to the specific category or not.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You want to compare with category id or category description ?

Comment: category id and if it matches echo the product description

Comment: try with my below answer

Comment: yeah tried it, doesn't echo the product description at all now

Comment: may be you should compare with correct category, because code seems correct for me

Comment: Codes from below works. Is 428 the right ID?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $catdesc=false;
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    if(in_array(428, $_product->getCategoryIds()))
    {
        $catdesc=true;
        break;
    }
?>

<?php if($catdesc): ?>
    <span><?php echo $_product->getDescription(); ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: hm doesn't seem to work- doesn't show the product description at all now

Answer (score 0):

`<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId); ?>`

```
<?php if(in_array(428, $_product->getCategoryIds())): ?>
    <span><?php echo $_product->getDescription(); ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the job with this two line:

```
<?php
if(in_array(428, $_product->getCategoryIds())){
    echo "<span>" . $_product->getDescription() . "</span>";
}
?>
```

Probably the code of the other guys does not work because they have redeclared $ _product.